# Проблема с создание вектора в классе, С++

Tags: c++, вектор

Я создаю вектор ссылок на объекты моего класса в главной функции - всё работает замечательно. Создаю схожий вектор в ином классе - всё работать перестаёт. Ссылается на какие-то странные ошибки:

> Необъявленный идентификатор
>
> синтаксическая ошибка: >
>
> std::vector: слишком мало аргументов шаблон

Вектор объявляю таким образом:

```
private:
    std::vector<className*> objects;
```

Как я уже сказал, точно такой же код замечательно работает в функции Main.

```
#pragma once 
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp> 
#include "Terrain.h" 
#include <vector> 
class Menu 
{ 
public: 
Menu(); 
~Menu(); 
private: 
std::vector<MenuSprites*> sprites;
```

ClassB.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Class.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();
private:
    std::vector<ClassB*> a;
};
```

Class.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "ClassB.h"

class Class
{
public:
    Class();
    ~Class();
private:
    std::vector<ClassB*> a;
};
```

Основная функции и .cpp все стандартные. Ошибка возникает.

Comment: Приведите весь код, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Harry Добавил к вопросу.
Упрощённый хэдер.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Harry, добавил код.

Comment: Взял ваши `class.h` и `classb.h`, и код типа `#include "Class.h"
#include "ClassB.h"

int main()
{
    ClassB cb;
    Class  c;
}` (извините за форматирование, но - комментарий!) - и все компилируется. ЧТО ИМЕННО не компилируется у вас?

Comment: @Harry Вот в именно таком формате, не компилируется в Class.h строчка std::vector<ClassB*> a;
Ошибки я указал выше.

Comment: Чем компилируете? Да, попробуйте просто внести тексты .h-файлов в cpp-файл - если не компилируется, дайте полный текст такого самодостаточного cpp-файла.

Answer (score 1):

ClassB.h включает Class.h, в котором есть `std::vector<ClassB*> a;`.
Т.к. ClassB еще не определен, то возникает ошибка "Необъявленный идентификатор".

Замените `#include "ClassB.h"` на `class ClassB;` там где не требуется полное определение класса.
Или напишите `std::vector<class ClassB*>`.

Answer (score -1):

Почему у вас файл ClassB.h подключает самого себя и подключает Class.h?
Попробуйте такой вариант:

Class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include "ClassB.h"

class Class
{
public:
    Class();
    ~Class();
private:
    std::vector<ClassB*> a;
};
#endif //CLASS_H
```

ClassB.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

#include <vector>

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB(){};
    ~ClassB();
private:
    std::vector<ClassB*> a;
};

#endif //CLASSB_H
```

Comment: Это ни при чем, из-за `#pragma once` эта директива будет просто проигнорирована.